# Getting Status: 200, Method: OPTIONS, 0kb in AJAX request instead of JSON file (Polymer)

Tags: json, ajax, xml, polymer

If I directly access the following API URL (with params included), it returns a valid JSON file. However, in trying use Polymer's AJAX component, I get the following result:

**Status: 200 | Method: OPTIONS | Type: XML | 0kb | Response: (blank)**

```
<iron-ajax 
      auto 
      url="https://api.bookeo.com/v2/bookings/" 
      params='
          {
          "secretKey":"xxxxxxxxxx", 
          "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxx" ,
          "startTime": "2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
          "endTime": "2016-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
          }' 
      handle-as="json" 
      content-type="application/json"
      on-response="handleResponse" 
      method="GET"
      last-response="{{item}}" 
 ></iron-ajax>
```

DETAILS for api.bookeo.com: *Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"*

I saw that and thought perhaps I should change the content-type to content-type="application/xml" but that still doesn't work. This is my first time working with an API, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my Polymer app.

Comment: Sounds like it might simply be a CORS preflight request …

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Looked at other questions and found I should be using the "byutv-jsonp" Polymer element. Tried it, and it's successfully returning the JSON.